# Как преобразовать строку в timestamp

Tags: c#

Есть строка

```
20171215220000 +0300
```

Как преобразовать его в timestamp?

Данный код например получает текущий timestamp

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

Как я понимаю надо строку в DateTime перевести,но не знаю как

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас реально unix timestamp, то так:

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(20171215220000L).UtcDateTime
```

Но ваша строка не выглядит как unix timestamp: в ней явно видно 2017 год, 12 месяц и 15 число, и ещё часовой пояс. Скорее всего, вам нужно это:

```
var s = "20171215220000 +0300";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dt = dto.UtcDateTime;
```